# Regular expression to replace a value in query parameter

Tags: java, regex

I get a query string from url by saying request.queryString() as -

```
supplyId=123456789b&search=true
```

I want to replace the value for **"supplyId"** with a new value. **"supplyId"** can come at any position in the query string. What would be the possible regular expression for this?

Comment: Why use a regular expression when you know what your delimiters look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't actually use regex for this, but string manipulation. Search for the position of "supplyId=" in the URL, then grab everything until the end of the string or "&", whichever comes first.

If you have to use a regex, try one of these:

```
(?<=supplyId=)[^&]+

supplyId=([^&]+)
```

Make sure case sensitivity is off. If you use the second pattern, the value you want will be in capture group 1.

Comment: what happens if value is: abcdsupplyId=value

Comment: @djmj - That shouldn't be a problem, since the string on the left of the `=` is the parameter name. You could just give your other parameters names that don't end in `supplyid`. But just for fun, you can solve that by adding `\b` to the beginning: `(?<=\bsupplyId=)[^&]+` or `\bsupplyId=([^&]+)`

Comment: Isn't `\b` for empty word? The delimiter `&` or query separator `?` should be detected at front unless they are escaped.

Comment: @djmj - `\b` means a [word boundary.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) It will prevent any letter, number, or underscore before `supplyId`, so `&` and `?` will both trigger it. BTW, you can't escape those in a URL, unless you were talking about hexadecimal URL encoding. Any hex-encoded character would end in `[0-9A-F]`, all of which would be blocked by `\b` as it should be. But as I said, it's basically moot. You're only matching the parameter name, which you yourself control.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should be able to do something like so:

```
String queryString = "supplyId=123456789b&search=true";
String anyStringIlike = "someValueIlike";
String newQueryString = queryString.replaceAll("supplyId=[^&]+","supplyId=" + anyStringIlike);
System.out.println(queryString);
System.out.println(newQueryString);
```

This should print:

> supplyId=123456789b&search=true
>
> supplyId=someValueIlike&search=true

Comment: what happens if value is: `abcdsupplyId=value` ?

Answer (score 2):

In perl you could do something like this.

perl -le '@m = ( "garbare=i123123123asdlfkjsaf&supplyId=123456789b&search=true" =~ /supplyId=(\d+\w+)&/g ); print for @m

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String updateQueryString (String queryString, String name, String value) {
if (queryString != null) {
      queryString = queryString.replaceAll(name + "=.*?($|&)", "").replaceFirst("&$", "");
   }
 return addParameter(queryString, name, value);
}

public static String addParameter(queryString, name, value) {      
  return StringUtils.isEmpty(queryString) ? (name + "=" + value) : (queryString + "&" + name + "=" + value);

}
```

You call like: `updateQueryString("supplyId=123456789b&search=true", "supplyId", "newValue");`

output:  `search=true&supplyId=newValue`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestQueryStringValReplace {    
   public static String replace(String queryString, String propName, String newVal) {
       return queryString.replaceAll(propName+"=[^&]+", propName+"=" + newVal);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Assert.assertEquals("supplyId=newVal&search=true", replace("supplyId=oldVal&search=true", "supplyId","newVal"));
       Assert.assertEquals("supplyId=newVal", replace("supplyId=oldVal", "supplyId","newVal"));
       Assert.assertEquals("search=true&supplyId=newVal&3rdprop=val", replace("search=true&supplyId=oldVal&3rdprop=val", "supplyId","newVal"));
   }
```

}